# SQLite как сортировать данные?

Tags: java, android, база-данных, android-studio, sqlite

Здравствуйте! Суть вопроса такова, делаю простенький quiz game, у пользователя есть выбор категорий. Не могу понять как сортировать вопросы в базе данных на категории

```
myDatabase = db;

    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUESTION + " ( "
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUESTION
            + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTD + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTE + " TEXT)";

    db.execSQL(sql);

    addQuestions();
```

В методе addQuestions() лежат вопросы. Нужно сделать так чтобы при выборе категории должны выходить вопросы связанные с ней.
Буду благодарен за любую помощь! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: почитайте про азы SQL, в частности `where` & `order by`. Это все что я понял из вопроса. Также я не понимаю почему и как в методе `addQuestions()` лежат вопросы?

Comment: Попробуйте разделить вопрос на части, сейчас он чересчур общий. Отвечающему понадобится описать как создать  модель данных в SQLite, как выбрать данные в Java, как их показать в андроид. Выберите какую-то одну часть, с которой возникают проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте родительскую таблицу `Категории` , от неё сделайте внешний ключ к таблице `QUESTION`.

В таблице категории создайте поля: `id, название_категории`, и в таблицу `QUESTION` соответственно добавьте поле `категория_id`, что бы было понятно к какой категории принадлежит вопрос.